# Can we say that any segment tree is balanced?

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, tree-balancing

Complexity of the operation in the segment tree is equal to the O(logn) on the basis of this can we say that any segment tree is balanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "the operation" you're talking about consists of traversing a path from the root to some leaf, then yes, "having max height of O(log n)" sound like a good balance criteria, I would say even a definition :)